# How can I get the content of body element by using html5lib in Python?

Tags: python, html5lib

How can I get the content of `<body>` element by using `html5lib` in Python?

Example input data: `<html><head></head><body>xxx<b>yyy</b></hr></body></html>`

Expected output: `xxx<b>yyy</b></hr>`

It should work even if HTML is broken (unclosed tags,...).

Answer (score 5):

`html5lib` allows you to parse your documents using a variety of standard tree formats. You can do this using [lxml](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/), as I've done below, or you can follow the instructions in their [user documentation](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/wiki/UserDocumentation) to do it either with [minidom](http://wiki.python.org/moin/MiniDom), [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html).

```
file = open("mydocument.html")
doc = html5lib.parse(file, treebuilder="lxml")
content = doc.findtext("html/body", default=None):
```

**Response to comment**

It is possible to acheive this without installing any external libs using their own  [simpletree.py](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/source/browse/python/html5lib/treebuilders/simpletree.py?r=2e90f1f70e905c5486b2d6db44dafe611d12a91a), but judging by the comment at the start of the file 
I would guess this is not the recommended way...

```
# Really crappy basic implementation of a DOM-core like thing
```

If you still want to do this, however, you can parse the html document like so:

```
f = open("mydocument.html")
doc = html5lib.parse(f)
```

and then find the element you're looking for by doing a breadth-first search of the child nodes in the document. The nodes are kept in an array named `childNodes` and each node has a name stored in the field `name`.

Comment: Don't you have a solution that does not require me to install other python modules?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/wiki/UserDocumentation, under "Parsing HTML," can help you there.  BeautifulSoup is probably the best choice if you don't have a reason to trust that the HTML is well-formed.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, I wanted the entire data inside the `<body>`, and it looks that this does return only the text (not entities).

Comment: @sorin I've added a new block in my answer in response to your first comment. With regards to this second comment, changing the call from `findtext` to simply `find` will give you the entire element.